# SharePoint Modern - Move To/Copy To function not populating Recent sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

Has anyone noticed a change/issue where the Move To/Copy to function no longer populates a list of Recent Sites?

Some tenancies that we manage, shows the recent sites on a list but another more recent SharePoint Hub/Hub site set up doesn't populate any recent sites on the Move To/Copy To box, even when clicking on "More Places" it only shows "your teams" and not "recent sites"

This occurs on both Communication sites and Team sites (Connected and not connected).

I've tried re-indexing the sites, selected follow and unfollow multiple times but nothing has
worked. Have submitted a ticket with MS but they are unable to figure it out as of yet.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Yes I have. Something that used to just work is now completely broken! It is driving us insane. We can't move content anywhere anymore. Very very frustrating and annoying.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/120590)